# I can not see my log in Android

Tags: java, android, logging

I put the following excerpts log in my Android application:

```
Log.w (TAG_NAME, "Hello Log - Warning!");
System.out.println ("CardapioWeb: xml downloaded:" + xmlBaixadoComSucesso);
```

When running the application in Eclipse, I can smoothly view these logs in Eclipse LogCat Tab.

The problem occurs when I install the application on a real phone (Galaxy S4 for example). I export the system log using various apps, but does not appear in that log no one of my excerpts.
My log is not displayed in a real cell, only in Android Emulator . I need something to enable the log show?

Thanks'

Comment: Here's an excerpt from the log I just export the cell:
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
08-28 14:15:41.116 14792 14792 I dalvikvm: Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 7...
08-28 14:16:05.256 14792 14792 D GestureDetector: [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 5 mFalseSizeCnt:0
08-28 14:16:05.266 14792 14792 D ProgressBar: setProgress = 0

Comment: Next to Log tab there is a tab called Device. Choose your device from there and then switch to Log window.

Comment: Try plugging in your device again and restart your Eclipse. Sometimes it happens to me

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Android 4.1, applications can only see their own log statements. You wrote that you used various apps to export the logs, so that may be the reason why you don't see it.

Comment: Dear, I used applications such as aLogCat (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) and Log Viewer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yuku.logviewer) to view the system log. And not in the log lines that my application recorded.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the problem. These applications do no longer work on newer Androids unless you have a rooted phone and install them as a system app.